# Intermittent segmentation fault, have coredump

Tags: python, multithreading, segmentation-fault, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a multi-threaded application which runs HTTP requests using the [python-requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Although the homepage for `python-requests` states that the library is thread-safe, I suspect that the segfault is in `python-requests`. I don't see how `BeautifulSoup` might not be thread-safe, but I cannot rule out that possibility, either.

[Coredump here](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?fd02889a153e5449#yODKF41DYwnG2K3+iZ64cW5Uqwji8mW1XDXE/jJqwHQ=). (~800 KiB)

[Coredump here too for redundancy](https://friendpaste.com/XmXeIrZymKAiglANwRi8Z). (~800 KiB)

This is a summary of the relevant Python code:

```
import bs4
import requests
import time
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread


def get_response(url, phrase=''):
    proxy = '1.2.3.4:3128'
    proxy_config = { 'http':proxy, 'https':proxy, 'ftp':proxy }

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_config)
    except Exception as error:
        return False

    if response.status_code != 200:
        return False

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    for element in soup.select('p'):
        # Check some things
        if things_checked == True:
             write_result(str(things))

    return True


def write_result(things=''):
    global output_file

    try:
        output_file.write(things)
        output_file.flush()
    except Exception as error:
        return False


def main(urls, phrases=[]):
    global output_file

    try:
        output_file = open('output.txt', 'a+', 1)
    except Exception as error:
        return False

    for url in urls:
        for phrase in phrases:
            t = Thread(target=partial(get_response, url, phrase))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

    time.sleep(10) # Actually, other non-related code runs here.
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
    phrases = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
    main(urls, phrases)
```

Comment: This code has a syntax error (`if things_checked = True:`) and an unterminated `try` block in `write_result`. Also 'output.txt' is unquoted. You can't run it, you're running something else.

Comment: Does your summary code actually segfault?

Comment: `url` is undefined in `get_response`. Post the code that works and has the problem you want to solve.

Comment: You are starting the threads with daemon set to `True` but quitting immediately without waiting for them. Might that lead to a crash? Why `daemon = True`?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Thank you. I've got the summary code running now. The code flow is identical to the code flow on the production code. It seems that the production code only crashes under load, which makes me more sure than ever that the problem is in the threading. I cannot load the summary code enough to crash it. Might the core dump provide any insight? Thank you!